# Are circular class dependencies bad from a coding style point of view?

Tags: language-agnostic, oop, dependencies

Are circular class dependencies bad from a coding style point of view?

**Example:**

In a database application we have two classes, one encapsulating information about a single database (`DBInfo`) and one class which can create a database connection. (`ConnFactory`)

`DBInfo` has a `getConnection` method which uses `ConnFactory`to create a connection. But `ConnFactory` itself needs a `DBInfo` object to do so.

Like this: (Any coding styles disregarded for the sake of readability)

```
class DBInfo {
    String name;
    String connectionUrl;

    Connection getConnection() {
        return ConnFactory.getConnection(this);
    } 
}


class ConnFactory {
    Connection getConnection(DBInfo toWhat) {
        return new Connection(toWhat.connectionUrl);
    }
}
```

My co-workers argue that this is bad practice and it would be better if there were only one direction of dependencies and no circular ones like here.

Is this bad practice, an anti-pattern or a code smell? Are there any drawbacks?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In general, I would call circular dependencies a Code Smell. Note that the term 'Code Smell' mainly indicates that 'here is a piece of code that requires special attention, and is likely to benefit from redesign.'

In most cases I would strongly consider a design where a circular dependency is not necessary, but in rare cases it may be okay.

In your example, the ConnFactory seems redundant, but that may be because your example has been trimmed down. It seems to me, however, that the Connection creation logic would be better if it was moved to the DBInfo class. When you already have a class that contains data about a database, it seems only natural to make it responsible for creating a connection to that database.

Comment: I agree, however it isn't unnatural to have some kind of parent, child relationship where connection has a reference to DBInfo that created it and DBInfo caches/manages a list of connections created.

That being said, in this example if it is only the string we need from DBInfo I would only pass that as a parameter. As you already said from the sample code it isn't really clear why they need references to each other, which makes it hard to propose a correct refactoring.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, generally speaking circular dependencies are bad, though not always evil. Problems with circular dependencies include tight coupling, mutually dependent modules and generally domino effect, when changes in one module propagate to other modules.

That said, your code is violating Single Responsibility Principle in that `DBInfo` not only stores information about the database, but is also responsible for obtaining `Connection` objects. Remove that particular piece of functionality to a separate class and everything will be just fine.

Answer (score 8):

**Not necessarily**

I don't think circular dependencies at the **class** granularity level are bad. I don't see a problem if two, three or perhaps four classes are mutually dependent. (I am not saying this is something you want, but it can be ok in some circumstances).

It **is** a problem if you have mutual dependency at the package or module level, for all the reasons mentioned above and below.

Answer (score 4):

This code only works if `ConnFactory.getConnection()` is static.  A better solution would be to make `getConnection()` an instance method of `ConnFactory`.  Then your DBInfo can take a `ConnFactory` as an argument (possibly in a constructor, if you have an overloaded constructor).  However, I think the use of the static method for this case is more of a bad practice than the circular reference.

If you were to go this route, though, I would also make an interface `IConnFactory` that `DBInfo` would interact with and that `ConnFactory` would implement.  Then there is no circular reference -- both `DBInfo` and `ConnFactory` would depend on `IConnFactory`, which would depend on neither.

Comment: So basically you are saying, circular dependencies are ok, if the classes are not tightly coupled?

Comment: I guess that would be one way of putting it.  I think my point was, if you're tempted to use a circular dependency, then chances are you're (a) coupling things too tightly, and (b) doing something else wrong somewhere.  As Anton Gogolev points out in another answer, you're violating the Single Responsibility Principle, which exacerbates your problem.

Comment: @Daniel Pryden: +1 for the Single Responsibility Principle

Answer (score 2):

All I know is that circular dependencies can become a bit of a problem when you start using a Dependency Injection Framework such as Structure Map.   Most of these frameworks have trouble handling circular dependencies, sometimes resulting in a stack overflow exception (pardon the pun :-))  Therefore I tend to try to steer clear of it unless absolutely necessary and cannot be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

What about a bi-directional one-to-many relationship that is such a common case in any application using an ORM layer? Isn't this a case of a circular dependency?

Is it bad/code-smell  ?

Comment: Are you answering a question or asking one? If you are indeed asking then this might be better suited as a comment, in which case my response would be: yes; yes it's a code-smell. An ORM layer that's designed well can avoid circular dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Circular dependencies are bad because:

- two dependencies is more than one
- you can't incrementally test (without mocking one of them, which would be silly for small, closely coupled things).

You can do all the stuff with interfaces to break the circular dependency if required, but the straightforward minimal solution is to just make DBInfo a nested class of ConnFactory. A unit that references itself isn't circular.