# Python inheritance - name is not defined

Tags: python

I've got the following code (shortened for clarity):

face.py:

```
from frame import *

class Face(Frame):
    def hello(self):
        print 'hello'
```

frame.py:

```
from face import *

class Frame(object):
  def __init__(self, image):
    self.image = image
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2.py", line 2, in <module>
    from frame import *
  File "/home/code/iris/frame.py", line 4, in <module>
    from face import *
  File "/home/code/iris/face.py", line 7, in <module>
    class Face(frame.Frame):
NameError: name 'frame' is not defined
```

which I think is to do with the way I've either:

- Set up my 'imports'
- Set up my classes

Any ideas what I've done wrong? Also, if anyone can explain where 'import' is necessary that would be helpful!

Thanks!
Chris.

Comment: Why are you importing face from frame? You've got a circular import.

Comment: One of my Frame functions will create a new Face - so I figured I'd want it loaded, right?

Comment: Seems like you need to redesign your classes. Circular dependencies are not a good idea.

Comment: Frame is an image, and face is a copied region from the image, with extra methods. Frame.find_faces() should return Face objects, each of which are images themselves. What would be the 'right' structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are entering into the trap of circular dependency. Your face class is depending on the frame class and your frame class is depending on face class thus creating a circular deadlock like situation. Taking reference from  [Handle circular dependencies in Python modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113383/handle-circular-dependencies-in-python-modules)

There are ways around this problem in python:

`The good option: Refactor your code not to use circular imports. 
The bad option: Move one of your import statements to a different scope.`

Comment: Would the solution be to create a super class for Frame & Face, such that Frame & Face were side-by-side, and both could inherit common functions from the superclass?

Comment: @cjm2671 Yes that's a much better solution

Comment: A much simpler fix may be to drop the `from module import *` syntax and just import the module itself (and later use `module.obj` rather than just `obj`). If you only have class and function definitions at the top level, you can usually get away with circular imports.