# How to import class from class included by that class

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, circular-dependency

I got a weird problem that I wasn't been able to find answer all over the internet (or I don't know how to ask).

I have module **AAA.py**

```
from BBB import BBB
class AAA():
    def test(self):
        print 'AAAA'
        a = BBB()
```

and module **BBB.py**

```
class BBB():
    def __init__(self):
        print 'BBB'
```

then when I call

```
a = AAA()
a.test()
```

everything works as expected and I see output

```
AAAA
BBB
```

**BUT** when I try to import and use class AAA from module **BBB.py**

```
from AAA import AAA
class BBB():
    def __init__(self):
        print 'BBB'
```

I get following error

```
ImportError: cannot import name AAA
```

Any suggestions? I cant create circular dependencies in Python? I am using version Python 2.7.6 on Ubuntu

Comment: shouldn't it be `from AAA import AAA` ?

Comment: yes sorry, thats a typo, but thet doesnt solve my problem

Comment: Can you please put full traceback?

Comment: @WaxCage did you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113383/handle-circular-dependencies-in-python-modules?

Comment: Is it so that I cant use circular dependencies? In the question you sent me they write that its a sign of bad design, but what if I got some Log class and Environment class, In the Log class I need Environment to know, what level of logging to use and in Environment i want to log... whatever...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed - if `AAA.py` imports something from `BBB.py` at top level and vice versa, it doesn't work as intended.

There are two ways you can solve it:

1. Import the modules from each other. This way they are both present as their namespace and will be filled during the import process.

   So just do `import BBB` and use `BBB.BBB()` for instantiating the class:

   ```
   import BBB
   class AAA():
       def test(self):
           print 'AAAA'
           a = BBB.BBB()
   ```
2. Do the import where you need it:

   ```
   class AAA():
       def test(self):
           from BBB import BBB
           print 'AAAA'
           a = BBB()
   ```

   This way the link between the two modules is "looser" and not so tight.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to use a module in another one, you have to import it and so use `import your_module`. You have to type `your_module.foo()` if you want to use a method inside it. With the instruction `from your_module import attr1, foo1, [...]` you are modifying the module's global variables, so that you can use attr1 or the method foo1 as if they were in your module.
A concrete example is: if you want to use the `math` module, you type `import math` and when you want to use the constant pi you type `math.pi`, but if you are sure there will be no clash with the other names, you'll type `from math import pi` and you will use the constant `pi` as if you declared it in your module.

Comment: I don't understand how that answers my question?

Comment: Oh, you were asking for circular import. I didn't get it

Comment: Well I really didn't understood :D, it would be better to follow my example - I followed your instructions and instead of importing from AAA import AAA  (in BBB module) I imported whole AAA module (import AAA) and it started working. Thanks a lot!