# How to combine State design pattern and Depedancy injection

Tags: java, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I'm trying to understand how to combine them (if possible) in this Java 1.7 code:

```
class View{
private State _state;
}

abstract class State{
protected View _view;
}

class UserState extends State{}
class AdminState extends State {}
```

I've tried to understand them better using these articles: [dependency-injection](http://www.journaldev.com/2394/dependency-injection-design-pattern-in-java-example-tutorial) and [state-design-pattern](http://www.journaldev.com/1751/state-design-pattern-in-java-example-tutorial). But I ended only more confused.

My questions are:

- Can I somehow inject *States* in the View class and avoid keeping State instance ?
- What I am  missing in my code to achieve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This question is suffering from the XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) please edit it to fix it. In other words, while I know those two patterns I don't know enough about what you're trying to do to be able to help you.

Comment: +1 for the correction. Question is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is a common one for dependency injection beginners. You are trying to do Circular Dependency Injection. I consider [this article to be the canonical reference on the subject](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/01/circular-dependency-in-constructors-and-dependency-injection/). Read that article, it does a better job than I am about to do.

However, briefly: You are trying to do this (picture stolen from article):

```
+---------+      +---------+
|    A    |<-----|    B    |
|         |      |         |
|         |----->|         |
+---------+      +---------+
```

Which class do you inject first? If you are trying to create `B`, you need an `A`. But you can't make `A` without `B`. And on and on.

You could do a workaround like this:

```
public class A {
    private final B b;
    A(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}

public class B {
    private /*not-final*/ A a;
    public void setA(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

[But this is a code smell.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356304/are-circular-class-dependencies-bad-from-a-coding-style-point-of-view) It's better to instead do:

```
                         +---------+
+---------+              |    B    |
|    A    |<-------------|         |
|         |              |         |
|         |    +---+     |         |
|         |--->| C |<----|         |
|         |    +---+     +---------+
+---------+
```

[Read the article for the code sample](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/01/circular-dependency-in-constructors-and-dependency-injection/)