# Does order of service declaration matter when creating them in a module?

Tags: angularjs

Hey everyone just a structural question regarding services in Angular JS.

I have a module:

```
var mod = angular.module('myapp', []);

mod.config(function(){
    // some various config stuff
});
```

I create three services, where some of them have an onto dependency and some have a one-to-one dependency.

```
mod.service('service1', ['service2', function(service2){

}]);

mod.service('service2', ['service1', function(service1){

}]);

mod.service('service3', ['service1, service2', function(service1, service2){

}]);
```

Since they are all being declared upon the initialization of the module `myApp` then would this structure be allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If service1 depends on service2 and service2 depends on service1, then you've introduced circle dependencies and got a code smell in your application.
AngularJs is build upon dependency injection and the circle dependency disables it. In some cases this is a acceptable solution but in angularjs, it's not.

One way to solve this is to ask yourself if service1 and service2 should be one single service?

Read Marks great answer on circle dependencies [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356304/are-circular-class-dependencies-bad-from-a-coding-style-point-of-view) for a better explaination on that point.

Comment: @estus ok, I thought the modules were injected one by one in the main app and that didn't work. Thanks for learning me:)

Comment: No, it is ok even if they were different modules. The only time when order matters is the injection of service providers that belong to different modules.

Comment: @estus So then the answer from crownhill below is correct then?

Comment: @MarkHill Both answers are correct. The order is not a problem. But circular dependency is. You should get [$injector:cdep](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/cdep) from that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that, sure. The module itself should be loaded in `app.js` at which point all services contained within will be available for injection wherever, including other services.

That said, I'm not 100% sure what you're looking for. Is the above not working?

Comment: No this is the answer I'm looking for. I haven't tested the build yet, I just wanted to make sure if was an acceptable structure so I didn't waste a terribly large amount of time on something that wasn't going to work.