# incomplete type named in nested name specifier (in nested classes) C++

Tags: c++, c++98

I have those two classes that include each other like this:

```c
//A.hpp

#include "B.hpp"

class B;

class A {
   class AException : public std::exception {
      const char *what() const throw ();
   };
   // Some other members in which I use B class
};
```

```c
//B.hpp

#include "A.hpp"

class A;

class B {
   typedef A::AException AException;
   // Some other members in which I use A class
};
```

So I want to bring `A::AException` into the scope of `B`, so that I have `B::AException == A::AException`, but the `typedef` is throwing `incomplete type named in nested name specifier` at compilation. I can't figure out how to do this, is this even possible ? I tried using the `typename` keyword but it doesn't work since there is no template. Thanks for the help (I use C++98 standard for this project)

Comment: Why do you `#include "B.hpp"` into `A.hpp`? Do you really need this inclusion?

Comment: Circular dependency in code means that code is wrong - to much entangled. Best cure is break cycle (for example by introducing third class which both `A` and `B` depend on). Linked answer just hides more general problem. [See explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1356304/1387438).

Comment: @ChrisMM Not really, since it doesn't answer the `typedef` problem, unless it's possible to declare a class `typedef` under the class

Comment: Just move `AException` into its own header file then both 'A' and 'B' can just include that header